# Updating redux state

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I am trying to make my redux reducers more simple when updating state. For example, here is a reducer below:

```
const initialState = {
  emails: {
    id: {
      emailAddress: null,
      emailBody: null,
      emailSubject: null,
    },
  },
  calls: {},
};

function messaging(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.SET_EMAIL_ADDRESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        emails: {
          ...state.emails,
          [action.id]: {
            emailAddress: [action.emailAddress]
          },
        },
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default messaging;
```

I tried writing the reducer below instead, but webstorm is complaining that this is not proper notation. What am I doing wrong? Also, any suggestions on how to update state in a more cleaner fashion is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
case actionTypes.SET_EMAIL_ADDRESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    emails[action.id]: {
      ...state.emails[action.id],
      emailAddress: [action.emailAddress]
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your initial state

And to avoid overriding existing values for `emailBody` and `emailSubject`.

I would rewrite this way:

```
case actionTypes.SET_EMAIL_ADDRESS:
    const currentEmails = state.emails;
    const emailId = action.id;
    const emailAddress = action.emailAddress;

    const email = { ...currentEmails[emailId], emailAddress };
    const emails = { ...currentEmails, [emailId]: email };
    return { ...state, emails };
```

It always pays to use descriptive names!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the dynamic key inside square brackets.

```
case actionTypes.SET_EMAIL_ADDRESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    [state.emails[action.id]]: {
      ...state.emails[action.id],
      emailAddress: [action.emailAddress]
    },
  };
```

Comment: thanks. I actually think it should be `[state.emails[action.id]]` btw.

Comment: @Jimmy updated answer based on you comment. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've started using [immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) when reducers need to make changes to deeply nested state. eg..

```
import produce from "immer";

function messaging(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.SET_EMAIL_ADDRESS:
      return produce(state, draft => {
        draft.emails[action.id] = { emailAddress: [action.emailAddress] };
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```